# Why after downloading xml file content changed?

Tags: javascript

I converted json to xml  file using dicttoxml , i print result of xml file that gives exact format that was opened perfectly in internet explorer but when i tried to open downloaded xml file in explorer that was blank page .

result of xml file before download

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><root><item type="dict"><id type="int">5992</id><text type="str">Obama</text><annotations type="list"><item type="dict"><label type="int">7</label><start_offset type="int">0</start_offset><end_offset type="int">5</end_offset><user type="int">4</user></item></annotations><meta type="dict"></meta><annotation_approver type="null"></annotation_approver></item></root>
```

download file content looks like

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?><root><item type=\"dict\"><id type=\"int\">5992</id><text type=\"str\">Obama</text><annotations type=\"list\"><item type=\"dict\"><label type=\"int\">7</label><start_offset type=\"int\">0</start_offset><end_offset type=\"int\">5</end_offset><user type=\"int\">4</user></item></annotations><meta type=\"dict\"></meta><annotation_approver type=\"null\"></annotation_approver></item></root>"
```

**sample.js**

```
download() {
  this.isLoading = true;
  const headers = {};
  if (this.format === 'csv') {
    headers.Accept = 'text/csv; charset=utf-8';
    headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/csv; charset=utf-8';
  } else if (this.format === 'xml'){
      headers.Accept = 'text/xml;';
      headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/xml;';
  } else {
    headers.Accept = 'application/json';
    headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
  } 
  HTTP({
    url: 'docs/download',
    method: 'POST',
    responseType: 'blob',
    params: {
      q: this.format,
    },
    headers,
  }).then((response) => {
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute('download', 'file.' + this.format); // or any other extension
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    this.isLoading = false;
    link.click();
  }).catch((error) => {
    this.isLoading = false;
    this.handleError(error);
  });
}
```

I think error at http content-type in javascript file , but i don't know how to fix it . Please suggest how to fix this problem .

Comment: `headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/csv; charset=utf-8';`, `headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/xml;';` and `headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';`. All of these almost certainly make no sense. In the context of a request, the content-type header tells the server what format you are using to send the parameter data to the server. It has nothing to do with the format that the response data is downloaded in. I think you should remove these lines.

Comment: P.S. Why are you going to all this trouble anyway? Why not just make the `/docs/download` endpoint accept a GET request, with the `type` specified as a querystring parameter? Then you could replace all of this javascript with simply `window.location = "/docs/download?q=" + this.format;`